# MYSQL: Find data where the condition have comma seperator

Tags: mysql

I have table wla_user and table wla_container. I want to display data from container table if certain condition met from the table User.

**Table wla_user**

| id | u_name | email | factory_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Halimah | halimah@gmail.com | 1,2 |

**Table wla_container**

| id | contNUm | contStatus | factory_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2122 | Active | 1 |
| 2 | 3312 | Active | 2 |
| 3 | 5123 | Not Active | 3 |
| 4 | 9817 | ACtive | 4 |

So if the user id = 1, The data that i want to look like is this:

| id | contNUm | contStatus | factory_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2122 | Active | 1 |
| 2 | 3312 | Active | 2 |

I try run this query. but then only show 1 data, which is factory 1. Suppose should be two data because the user factory is 1,2

```
SELECT id, contNUm, contStatus, factory_id 
FROM wla_container WHERE factory_id IN (SELECT factory_id FROM wla_user WHERE email = 'halimah@gmail.com')
```

Can anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid storing comma separated data in your tables.  As a workaround, we can try using `FIND_IN_SET()` on the `factory_id` column in the `wla_user` table:

```sql
SELECT id, contNUm, contStatus, factory_id
FROM wla_container wc
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM wla_user wu
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET(wc.factory_id, wu.factory_id) > 0
);
```